# List javascript urls of a page

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control, require

is there a way I can extract the list of all the JS imported in a page, maybe via browser console? I'm not looking for only the ones imported via , but also the ones imported by other js scripts.

So, let's say I have a page that is using requirejs, and during the usage of the page, many other JS files are loaded. How can I list these files imported URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You follow this code and get all URLs in `urlsArray` variables

like this output image.
[image: result array]

```
var urlsArray = [];

[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll("script[src]"), function( src ) { 
  urlsArray.push(src.src);
});
console.log(urlsArray);
```

#### Thanks [sayed021]

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough solution, only I've been a *bit* lazy in converting the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) into an array via using the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax, since you can't use the `map` function on a NodeList.

```js
const srcs = [... document.querySelectorAll("script[src]")].map(s => s.src);
console.log(srcs);
```

```html
<script src="test1"></script>
<script src="test2"></script>
```